# Pasar opciones de un select list a otro con jQuery limitando las opciones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Tengo dos select list, uno de origen y otro de destino, pero estoy limitando a 3 las opciones para el select destino. Lo limito con un contador que se incrementa cada vez que presionas el botón de pasar a la izquierda. Para evitar incrementar el contador sin seleccionar ninguna opción lo que hago es deshabilitar el botón de pasar a izquierda hasta que no se seleccione alguna opción.

La idea es la misma para el botón de pasar a la derecha, pero el contador en este caso resta.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Pasar opciones de un select list a otro con jQuery</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


    <style>
    body{width:600px;margin:0 auto;overflow-x:hiden;}
    select{width:180px;margin:0 0 50px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .clear{clear:both;text-align:center}
    div{float:left;width:200px;text-align:center}
    input {margin:25px 1px 0 1px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
    .izq{border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .der{border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;}
    select: disabled { background:#DD2D30; border:1px solid red;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pasar opciones de un select list a otro con jQuery</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formulario">
        <div>
            <select name="origen[]" id="origen"  size="8" >
                <option value="1">Opci&oacute;n 1</option>
                <option value="2">Opci&oacute;n 2</option>
                <option value="3">Opci&oacute;n 3</option>
                <option value="4">Opci&oacute;n 4</option>
                <option value="5">Opci&oacute;n 5</option>
                <option value="6">Opci&oacute;n 6</option>
                <option value="7">Opci&oacute;n 7</option>
                <option value="8">Opci&oacute;n 8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" class="pasar izq" value="Pasar &raquo;" id="pasar_izq" name="pasar_izq" disabled><input type="button" class="quitar der" id="pasar_der" name="pasar_der" value="&laquo; Quitar" disabled><br />

        </div>
        <div class="">
            <select name="destino[]" id="destino" size="8"></select>
        </div>
        <p class="clear"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Procesar formulario"></p>
    </form>

    <div id="content">0</div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
                 var x = 0; //Initial field counter is 1

            $("select#origen").change(function () {
                    if(x != 3) {
                        $("#pasar_izq").prop("disabled", false);

                    }
                alert($('#origen option').length);
             }); 


            $('#pasar_izq').click(function() { 
                    if(x < 3){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                        x++; //Increment field counter
                        $("#pasar_izq").prop("disabled", true);     
                        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;
                        return !$('#origen option:selected').remove().appendTo('#destino');
                    }
            });


            $(document).on('change','#destino',function(){
                if(x != 0) {
                        $("#pasar_der").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                alert($('#destino option').length);
                });



            $('#pasar_der').click(function() { 
                    if(x >= 1){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                        x--; //Increment field counter
                        $("#pasar_der").prop("disabled", true);     
                        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = x;
                        return !$('#destino option:selected').remove().appendTo('#origen'); 
                    }
            });


        $('.submit').click(function() { $('#destino option').prop('selected', 'selected'); });

    }); 

    </script>
```

El problema que tengo es cuando solamente paso una opción a la derecha esta función **$(document).on('change','#destino',function(){ ...});** no funciona, y el botón de pasar a la derecha no se deshabilita, es como si con 1 opción no funcionase ya que cuando pasas dos o más opciones si que se habilita.

¿Alguien sabe alguna solución?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona con el evento `onchange` porque la opción agregada queda automáticamente seleccionada y no hay posibilidad de disparar el evento.

Sugiero cambiar el evento a `click` y verificar que haya una opción seleccionada para habilitar los botones, lo que también evita el uso del contador `x`, ya que puedes obtenerlos directamente de las opciones disponibles en *destino*

Finalmente, cuando pasas un elemento con el botón *Pasar* activa el botón *Quitar*, porque hay un elemento seleccionado en *destino* y se hace lo mismo en sentido inverso.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cambiar evento change por click
    $("select#origen").click(function () {
        // Verificar cantidad de opciones en destino y que origen tiene una seleccionada
        if($('#destino option').length != 3 && $('#origen option:selected').length > 0) {
            $("#pasar_izq").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        console.log($('#origen option').length);
    }); 

    $('#pasar_izq').click(function() { 
        // Probablemente sobra la comparación
        if($('#destino option').length < 3){
            $("#pasar_izq").prop("disabled", true);     
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = $('#destino option').length;
            $('#origen option:selected').remove().appendTo('#destino');
            // Habilitar botón "Quitar"
            $("#pasar_der").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','#destino',function(){
        if($('#destino option').length != 0 &&  $('#destino option:selected').length > 0) {
            $("#pasar_der").prop("disabled", false);
        }
        console.log($('#destino option').length);
    });

    $('#pasar_der').click(function() { 
        if($('#destino option').length >= 1){
            $("#pasar_der").prop("disabled", true);     
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = $('#destino option').length;
            $('#destino option:selected').remove().appendTo('#origen');
            // Al quitar opción, habilitar el botón "Pasar"
            $("#pasar_izq").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });


    $('.submit').click(function() { $('#destino option').prop('selected', 'selected'); });

});
```

```css
body{width:600px;margin:0 auto;overflow-x:hiden;}
    select{width:180px;margin:0 0 50px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .clear{clear:both;text-align:center}
    div{float:left;width:200px;text-align:center}
    input {margin:25px 1px 0 1px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
    .izq{border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .der{border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;}
    select: disabled { background:#DD2D30; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Pasar opciones de un select list a otro con jQuery</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formulario">
        <div>
            <select name="origen[]" id="origen"  size="8" >
                <option value="1">Opci&oacute;n 1</option>
                <option value="2">Opci&oacute;n 2</option>
                <option value="3">Opci&oacute;n 3</option>
                <option value="4">Opci&oacute;n 4</option>
                <option value="5">Opci&oacute;n 5</option>
                <option value="6">Opci&oacute;n 6</option>
                <option value="7">Opci&oacute;n 7</option>
                <option value="8">Opci&oacute;n 8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" class="pasar izq" value="Pasar &raquo;" id="pasar_izq" name="pasar_izq" disabled><input type="button" class="quitar der" id="pasar_der" name="pasar_der" value="&laquo; Quitar" disabled><br />

        </div>
        <div class="">
            <select name="destino[]" id="destino" size="8"></select>
        </div>
        <p class="clear"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Procesar formulario"></p>
    </form>

    <div id="content">0</div>
```

Comment: Magnifico!!!! muchas gracias, funciona muy bien, es exactamente lo que quería.
Muchas gracias de verdad. Ahora a intentar entender el código :)